# How to count neurons in a simple Tensorflow program?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensor

I'm new to Tensorflow and hence I'm still finding my way around.

I guess I know what a neuron is according to Tensorflow. (A neuron accepts an input and produces an output)

Now, in case of a simple program with code like

```
c = tf.multiply(a, b)
e = tf.add(c,d)
```

Here, does this program contain 2 neurons?

Answer (score 1):

Considering your example:

c is a output neuron where as a and b are input neurons to it.

and e is again a output neuron and input neuron to e are c and d.

Your network would look like. 
[image]

Total neurons are 5,
3 input, 1 hidden and 1 output.

Hope this helps, feel free to ask any further questions.

Comment: Thanks for the simple and easy explanation. Appreciate it.